# What beans are registered by the spring security namespace

Tags: xml, spring, spring-security

Hi I'm trying to customize spring security configuration for the 'access-decision-manager-ref' attribute in 'global-method-security' and I know spring security has default bean configurations for this work (in spring security namespace), but I want to customize these configurations so I need to know if there is somewhere I could find the default spring security beans configuration so I have the guidance I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, each `XBeanDefinitionParser` should document the beans it is registering. In your case, check `SecurityNamespaceHandler` to see what parser it is using for your element, and then check the javadoc. If there's nothing there, you'd have to read the code of the parser. It's tedious.

But even when you read it, you can't easily customize it. One way is to register a `BeanPostProcessor` to post-process the beans registered automatically.