# Spring XML namespaces : How do I find what are the implementing classes behind them?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In my Spring 3.1 application, I sometime need to change the default behavior of some of the Spring namespaces in my context files. To do that, I create custom classes that implement some interfaces or that extend the default classes Spring uses.

But I find it hard to know exactly what are those classes that Spring uses behind its namespaces! What is the steps required to find them?

For example, the security namespace :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
```

and something like :

```
<sec:http>
    ...
    <sec:logout />
</sec:http>
```

How do I find what classes are used by the "<sec:logout />" namespace? I don't find the information by looking at http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd !

Where should I look?

Comment: As far as I know, XML namespaces don't necessarily have anything to do with classes.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Every Spring namespace has an associated [`NamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/NamespaceHandler.html) implementation. The namespace schemas are mapped to schema files inside Spring JARs in various `spring.schemas` files (see also [Spring DI applicationContext.xml how exactly is xsi:schemaLocation used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768873)).

The XML schema namespaces are also mapped to handler classes in `spring.handlers` files (several as each Spring JAR might introduce different namespaces). For your convenience here is a list of most common namespaces:

## Spring core

- `aop` - [`AopNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/config/AopNamespaceHandler.html)
- `c` - [`SimpleConstructorNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/SimpleConstructorNamespaceHandler.html)
- `cache` - [`CacheNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/config/CacheNamespaceHandler.html)
- `context` - [`ContextNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/config/ContextNamespaceHandler.html)
- `jdbc` - [`JdbcNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/config/JdbcNamespaceHandler.html)
- `jee` - [`JeeNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ejb/config/JeeNamespaceHandler.html)
- `jms` - [`JmsNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/config/JmsNamespaceHandler.html)
- `lang` - [`LangNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scripting/config/LangNamespaceHandler.html)
- `mvc` - [`MvcNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/MvcNamespaceHandler.html)
- `oxm` - [`OxmNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/oxm/config/OxmNamespaceHandler.html)
- `p` - [`SimplePropertyNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/SimplePropertyNamespaceHandler.html)
- `task` - [`TaskNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/config/TaskNamespaceHandler.html)
- `tx` - [`TxNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/config/TxNamespaceHandler.html)
- `util` - [`UtilNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/UtilNamespaceHandler.html)

## Spring Security

- `security` - [`SecurityNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/SecurityNamespaceHandler.html)
- `oauth` - [`OAuthSecurityNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth/config/OAuthSecurityNamespaceHandler.html)

## Spring integration

- `int` - [`IntegrationNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/config/xml/IntegrationNamespaceHandler.html)
- `amqp` - [`AmqpNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/amqp/config/AmqpNamespaceHandler.html)
- `event` - [`EventNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/event/config/EventNamespaceHandler.html)
- `feed` - [`FeedNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/feed/config/FeedNamespaceHandler.html)
- `file` - [`FileNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/file/config/FileNamespaceHandler.html)
- `ftp` - [`FtpNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/ftp/config/FtpNamespaceHandler.html)
- `gemfire` - [`GemfireIntegrationNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/gemfire/config/xml/GemfireIntegrationNamespaceHandler.html)
- `groovy` - [`GroovyNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/groovy/config/GroovyNamespaceHandler.html)
- `http` - [`HttpNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/http/config/HttpNamespaceHandler.html)
- `ip` - [`IpNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/ip/config/IpNamespaceHandler.html)
- `jdbc` - [`JdbcNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/jdbc/config/JdbcNamespaceHandler.html)
- `jms` - [`JmsNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/jms/config/JmsNamespaceHandler.html)
- `jmx` - [`JmxNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/jmx/config/JmxNamespaceHandler.html)
- `mail` - [`MailNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/mail/config/MailNamespaceHandler.html)
- `redis` - [`RedisNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/redis/config/RedisNamespaceHandler.html)
- `rmi` - [`RmiNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/rmi/config/RmiNamespaceHandler.html)
- `script` - [`ScriptNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/scripting/config/jsr223/ScriptNamespaceHandler.html)
- `security` - [`IntegrationSecurityNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/security/config/IntegrationSecurityNamespaceHandler.html)
- `sftp` - [`SftpNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/sftp/config/SftpNamespaceHandler.html)
- `stream` - [`StreamNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/stream/config/StreamNamespaceHandler.html)
- `twitter` - [`TwitterNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/twitter/config/TwitterNamespaceHandler.html)
- `ws` - [`WsNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/ws/config/WsNamespaceHandler.html)
- `xml` - [`IntegrationXmlNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/xml/config/IntegrationXmlNamespaceHandler.html)
- `xmpp` - [`XmppNamespaceHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/xmpp/config/XmppNamespaceHandler.html)

If you browse to the source of each of these classes you will quickly discover various `BeanDefinitionParser` implementations responsible for parsing actual XML definitions.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz! This, mixed with some of the tricks by ericacm helped me a alot. In eclipse (for those using it), opening the "Type hierarchy" for NamespaceHandler and BeanDefinitionParser also helps.

Comment: For Spring Batch: `batch`-[CoreNamespaceHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/xml/CoreNamespaceHandler.html)

Comment: Hazelcast `hz` [HazelcastNamespaceHandler](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6-EA/javadoc/com/hazelcast/spring/HazelcastNamespaceHandler.html)

Answer (score 2):

Almost all of them are named `*BeanDefinitionParser`.   First step is, using your browser, bring up the Spring JavaDocs and hit `<Ctrl>-F` (or `<Command>-F`).   Search for BeanDefinitionParser.  Of the classes that match, one or two will, by their names, look like they handle the namespace elements you are researching.  It may take a bit of looking at the source code to those classes but you'll ultimately find what you want.

Alternatively, in your IDE, you can browse to `BeanDefinitionParser.java` and then do "Find Usages" (IntelliJ) or "Type Hierarchy" (Eclipse) to find all of the implementers of that interface.  There are a handful of classes that don't follow the `*BeanDefinitionParser` naming convention. Your IDE will give you a comprehensive list.

I think that Spring should actually document, in the Namespace section of their reference docs, the names of the classes that handle each element.

Answer (score 1):

Every XML namespace is parsed by its [NamespaceHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/NamespaceHandler.html). The handler class for security namespace is [SecurityNamespaceHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/SecurityNamespaceHandler.html), which is specified in spring.handlers file inside META-INF of spring-security-config-XXX.jar file.

The http element is parsed by [HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/http/HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.html) and its child element logout is parsed by `org.springframework.security.config.http.LogoutBeanDefinitionParser`(package-protected).

Also see notes in [Coding a NamespaceHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/extensible-xml.html#extensible-xml-namespacehandler) and advice in [What beans are registered by the spring security namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960170/what-beans-are-registered-by-the-spring-security-namespace) if you are planning to customize it.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Spring Security, it's well documented: see [Appendix B. The Security Namespace](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html)

See also this blog post: [BEHIND THE SPRING SECURITY NAMESPACE](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/03/06/behind-the-spring-security-namespace/)